# Using ssd intensively. Should we worry?

Tags: ssd

I'm currently using conventional HDDs like the 5200 rpms, browsing a lot, my folder and files are scattered, torrenting always and I'm not fond of optimization like disabling cache, cleaning temp
Files , etc.

My question is, given the above conditions (no disable of cache, seeding always in torrent, downloading torrent) is it safe to use SSD? I'm pretty worried about cycles but I read an article wherein it says its safe since it will usually wear out for 10 years given that you always write heavily and continuously. Thanks

Comment: I have roughly the same situation you do, and I'm not worried...

Comment: Patrick, i really dont want to waste my tiedosabling cache, an impoving lifespan. I just want to use it the way i usuually do like doing heavy stuff like downloading a lot in torrent, seeog, heavy browsing, no caches. Whats your take on it

Comment: If use use it heavily, 24/7 for 20 years then worry. For anything less you only need to worry with the first generation drives. Any modern SSD will die after you have already discarded the entire computer.

Comment: I am not an expert when it comes to SSD technology, cycles or anything. All I can is speak from experience, and I personally have not had any issues or speed disadvantages in the 8 months or so I've been running the current SSD 24/7 in an iMac.

Comment: Why do you want an SSD when torrenting and browsing? You won't get much benefit (except boot times, if you're torrenting 24/7 you won't be doing), your bottleneck (in terms of torrenting) will always be your connection. Also torrenting implies you're downloading/uploading lots of data, SSD's have a much higher cost (per gb of data) than a mechanical drive. You're better looking at some of the better 7200 RPM drives (WD Raptors), you'll get speed and storage. Seagate also do a 'hybrid' drive (Monumentus) combining both types of storage - high capacity with speeds between mechanical and SSD.

Comment: Well other user said even if you do torrrnt to te max, it will last up to 20 years so by that time, other components might have daile already like mobo, cpu. So its still ok. Whats ur take on it?? Mr haydn

Comment: I'm sorry, but this discussion isn't going anywhere. SSDs are manufactured so that they actually work under normal usage, and you shouldn't have to worry about anything. Any SSD will wear out at some point, but all SSDs have different ratings depending on how much they are used per day, so you will have to compare these when shopping. If you want to talk about some special models consider coming to [chat]. Otherwise, please refrain from abusing comment threads as chat. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a reasonably modern SSD, you have nothing to worry about. An SSD actually has greater expected life than a hard drive under comparable load.

Comment: What do you think about intel 330?

Comment: Intel 330 review including how well it should last:  http://www.anandtech.com/show/5817/the-intel-ssd-330-review-60gb-120gb-180gb/3

Comment: The Intel 330 is rated for 3 years at 20GB written per day. However, this appears insanely conservative based on the specs of the chips it's made out of (it should last about 25 times this long). You can download the [full specs](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-specifications/ssd-330-specification.pdf).

Comment: @ david, whats ur take on samsung 830

Comment: @Wavepacket - Product suggestions and product reviews are not on topic on Stack Exchange.  You will need to find some other website and/or do your own research to make up your mind.  Comments are not designed for discussions such as this.